# How should I implement a terrain raise/lower brush?

Tags: algorithm, terrain, heightmap

I am trying to make an terrain editor. The terrain is described by a grayscale height map.
When I click at somewhere in the terrain map with the brush, the terrain should raise or lower about that clicked point. However, I don't know what is the correct function that describe height change of pixels around the clicked point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As agone says, there is no one function that's aways used for this, [but here are a few you can try (see "Falloff Functions" tab)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D_JAftzmGpzs5qM2UXRlgjANlHI6QJfl3x-KROXUJog/edit?usp=sharing):

[image: Spreadsheet with line chart of different falloff functions described below]

You can use Pythagorean theorem to get the distance between the clicked point and the pixel/vertex you want to modify. Then you can scale the amount of modification to apply by multiplying it by an "intensity" factor between zero and one. This works whether you're using the brush to raise/lower, smoothen, or blend with a sampled shape, texture, or noise map.

Here are a few ways to calculate that intensity factor, using a `minRadius` within which you always want to apply 100% effect, and a `maxRadius` outside which no pixels/vertices should be affected:

- **Step Function**: `(radius <= minRadius)? 1 : 0` this gives you a hard-edged disc-shaped brush with no antialiasing or feathering at the edges, appropriate if you want to create a sharp cliff, canyon, or well. But it will need some love to dress up the sharp sides.
- **Linear Falloff**: `Clamp(1 - (radius - minRadius)/(maxRadius - minRadius), 0, 1)` This gives a flat ramp between the high and low, with sharp corners where they meet. This is good for making artificial structures like earthen berms around road bridges.
- **Smoothstep**: `linear * linear * (3 - 2 * linear)` This modification to the linear falloff gives it an "ease in-out" curve, rounding out the sharp corners a the top and bottom of the ramp. This starts to look like a more natural eroded terrain, and will show fewer artifacts that need to be cleaned-up.
- **Smoothstep Squared**: `smoothstep * smoothstep` Raising the smoothstep function to a power makes it steeper, with a more gradual slope into the valley at the bottom, while keeping the curve at the top from pinching into a corner. You may find this looks more natural for some kinds of terrain.
- **Sinusoid**: `0.5 - 0.5 * Cos(linear * PI)` This looks almost identical to smoothstep, so you'd probably find the polynomial version works just as well.

There are lots more options you could try, but hopefully that gives you a framework for exploring some options. Many tools will give the user a choice between different brush modes with different falloff characteristics to let the terrain artist pick the right tool for the particular feature they're sculpting.

Answer (score 0):

The term you are looking for is falloff defined as any mathematical function class that uses a radius as the variable.

The falloff function should be a selection from one of the classes of functions: Linear, Polynomial, Logarithmic, Exponential, Trigonometric(restricted) about the radius.

Comment: I would like to know which one does currently existing terrain editor bush use. And, why do they use that function?

Comment: @martinrhan Nearly of all them. Because of the properties the functions exhibit over the radial space.